# How to know characters code for iPhone keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

How to know characters code for iPhone keyboard? The attached code only works for Cocoa Application.

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event{    
  NSLog(@"code= %d", [event keyCode]);   
  NSLog(@"code= %@", [event characters]);   
 }
```

Comment: *Note: Don't create duplicate questions...* The iOS virtual keyboard does not generate key codes. Are you looking to detect key codes when an external keyboard is being used? If so, you'll probably want to look into `UIKeyCommand` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand

Comment: please tell me how can I find time entering each character?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Perhaps if you described what you ***want to do*** instead.

Comment: I have a Textfield and keyboard iphone. I need to know the time when I click on the symbol on the keyboard.

Comment: I need it for my research.

Comment: Look at `UITextField` delegate for `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` ... that is probably what you need: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield?language=objc